Unreal Engine problem; Character face not importing correctly from blender to Unreal Engine 5
There is not a specific error message that it gives, but here is my problem:
I'm trying to import Makima (from Chainsaw Man) into Unreal Engine 5, I have her .fbx file (from blender). This is how she looks in Blender:

So I converted this into .fbx, went to Mixamo.com for some animations, which also automatically rigged her character (gave her bones), and then I import the downloaded .fbx model from Mixamo (the one where she got bones), and it looked like this:

This is a true confirmed skull moment. Anyone have any ideas to how I can fix this?
